# Django Postgres Connection Pooling

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku-postgres

How do you pool connections in Django v2.1 for a Postgres db? 
[This heroku library is no longer supported](https://github.com/heroku-python/django-postgrespool). On the Django website it has a section about [connection pooling](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/databases/#transaction-pooling-and-server-side-cursors) for pgBouncer but can't seem to find a tutorial online for getting setup with pgBouncer or an example project. Heroku also doesn't allow the pgBouncer buildpack for hobby tier databases, so if there is a way round this issue would be great. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You could try [`django-postgrespool2`](https://github.com/lcd1232/django-postgrespool2), a fork of `django-postgrespool` which you linked to.

Comment: @Alasdair `django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  too many connections for role` still thrown with django-postgrespool2, pool is always exceeded :(.

Comment: Depending on which tier of database you're using, you could leverage their [server-side connection pooling](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgres-connection-pooling).

Comment: @BradleyJohnson I'm on the free version of the hobby tier at the moment, I've also tried specifying the max connection age in Django settings for connection persistence but the connection pool is always overflown.

Comment: @BradleyJohnson Just an update to what I did to resolve this, so I ended up switching to AWS and started using docker, created my own docker container which now successfully use nginx, pgBouncer and gunicorn for my Django project. My Django application is now smooth as butter

Comment: Looks like Django 5.1 will support postgres connection pooling! https://github.com/django/django/pull/17914

Answer (score 2):

You could use [persistent connections](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/databases/#persistent-connections) instead of pooling connections.

Comment: why should we use persistent connection?

Comment: I use gevent worker via gunicorn, don't think it is playing well with persistent connections

Comment: Be careful with persistent connections when use async code on Django 4: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33497